When is a question considered a bug report?
I recently posted a question about Google Earth Engine API on how to compute the bounds of a projection (How to get the bounds of a projection in GEE). It's something I can do with other tools that I know and I was curious to understand how it was possible to do the same thing with GEE.
GEE has hundreds if not thousands of questions in this stack exchange community so I thought someone would come with a nice workaround. Unfortunately nothing appeared and the only answer provided was to make a request on GEE issue tracker. Which I did.
As the suggestion was coming from Noel themself, I thought this would have been updated rapidly and I would have answered my own question with the new method.
In the meantime someone has downvoted and tagged my question as off-topic. To me the question seemed perfectly legit as a "I don't know how to" problem and I don't understand why the same one asked about pyproj (that led to a modification of the pyproj lib) Getting Projected bounds information in pyproj was not tagged as well ?
Would it be possible to get my question back online, I'll post a python workaround and update my answer once the GEE team make a move

See the full close reason:

Questions that relate to the business of vendors and product teams,
such as licensing, pricing, release dates, submission of bug reports
and enhancement requests, etc, are off-topic here and should be
directed instead to the official software support teams.

From this I would think your question wasn't considered as a bug report (which is only one part of that close reason) but as an enhancement request.  Simply put, the functionality you were after didn't exist, and it was suggested you request it (which you did).
While I agree that it started out as a "how-to?" question, it became an enhancement request when the only answer was that it can't be done but you can request it.
If/when the GEE team respond to your request you can certainly flag your question for moderator attention asking for it to be reopened so that you can post an answer.
